# Prioritized subscriptions invocation

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I have a single observable sequence of messages. There is a set of subscribers that can handle these messages. Each subscriber has an execution priority. Each message must be handled once by the highest priority subscriber chosen from the list of currently subscribed subscribers. Subscribers are constantly subscribed/unsubscribed from the sequence, so we don't know the number and priorities of subscribers when constructing the sequence. Is it a possible/viable solution using rx?

To illustrate:

```
public class Message
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsConsumed { get; set; }
}

var subject = new Subject<Message>();
var sequence = subject.Publish().RefCount();

Action<Message, int> subscriber = (m, priority) =>
{
    if (!m.IsConsumed)
    {
        m.IsConsumed = true;
        Trace.WriteLine(priority);
    }
};

var s2 = sequence.Priority(2).Subscribe(m => subscriber(m, 2));
var s1 = sequence.Priority(1).Subscribe(m => subscriber(m, 1));

subject.OnNext(new Message()); // output: 1

s1.Dispose();
subject.OnNext(new Message()); // output: 2
```

The missing piece to make this solution work is the Priority method which do not exist in Rx library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a very interesting problem...

So, first off: I am not aware of any intrinsic Rx operators that can achieve a "routing" effect similar to what you want in this `Priority` extension.

That said, I was playing around in LINQPad over lunch today, and came up with a (very) hacky proof of concept that appears to work:

First, your message class

```
public class Message
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsConsumed { get; set; }
}
```

Next, the extension method wrapper-class:

```
public static class Ext
{    
    public static PrioritizedObservable<T> Prioritize<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
    {
        return new PrioritizedObservable<T>(source);
    }
}
```

And what is this `PrioritizedObservable<T>`?

```
public class PrioritizedObservable<T> 
   : IObservable<T>, IObserver<T>, IDisposable
{
    private IObservable<T> _source;
    private ISubject<T,T> _intermediary;
    private IList<Tuple<int, Subject<T>>> _router;

    public PrioritizedObservable(IObservable<T> source)
    {
        // Make sure we don't accidentally duplicate subscriptions
        // to the underlying source
        _source = source.Publish().RefCount();

        // A proxy from the source to our internal router
        _intermediary = Subject.Create(this, _source);
        _source.Subscribe(_intermediary);        

        // Holds per-priority subjects
        _router = new List<Tuple<int, Subject<T>>>();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _intermediary = null;
        foreach(var entry in _router)
        {
            entry.Item2.Dispose();
        }
        _router.Clear();
    }

    private ISubject<T,T> GetFirstListener()
    {
        // Fetch the first subject in our router
        // ordered by priority 
        return _router.OrderBy(tup => tup.Item1)
            .Select(tup => tup.Item2)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    void IObserver<T>.OnNext(T value)
    {
        // pass along value to first in line
        var nextListener = GetFirstListener();
        if(nextListener != null)
            nextListener.OnNext(value);
    }

    void IObserver<T>.OnError(Exception error)
    {
        // pass along error to first in line
        var nextListener = GetFirstListener();
        if(nextListener != null)
            nextListener.OnError(error);
    }

    void IObserver<T>.OnCompleted()
    {
        var nextListener = GetFirstListener();
        if(nextListener != null)
            nextListener.OnCompleted();
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> obs)
    {
        return PrioritySubscribe(1, obs);
    }

    public IDisposable PrioritySubscribe(int priority, IObserver<T> obs)
    {
        var sub = new Subject<T>();
        var subscriber = sub.Subscribe(obs);
        var entry = Tuple.Create(priority, sub);
        _router.Add(entry);
        _intermediary.Subscribe(sub);
        return Disposable.Create(() => 
        {
            subscriber.Dispose();
            _router.Remove(entry);
        });
    }
}
```

And a test harness:

```
void Main()
{
    var subject = new Subject<Message>();
    var sequence = subject.Publish().RefCount().Prioritize();

    Action<Message, int> subscriber = (m, priority) =>
    {
        if (!m.IsConsumed)
        {
            m.IsConsumed = true;
            Console.WriteLine(priority);
        }
    };

    var s3 = sequence.PrioritySubscribe(3, Observer.Create<Message>(m => subscriber(m, 3)));
    var s2 = sequence.PrioritySubscribe(2, Observer.Create<Message>(m => subscriber(m, 2)));
    var s1 = sequence.PrioritySubscribe(1, Observer.Create<Message>(m => subscriber(m, 1)));
    var s11 = sequence.PrioritySubscribe(1, Observer.Create<Message>(m => subscriber(m, 1)));

    subject.OnNext(new Message()); // output: 1

    s1.Dispose();
    subject.OnNext(new Message()); // output: 1
    s11.Dispose();

    subject.OnNext(new Message()); // output: 2
    s2.Dispose();
    subject.OnNext(new Message()); // output: 3

    sequence.Dispose();

}
```